# Strange behavior of sorted function

Tags: python

I have a very simple task of sorting list elements by frequency and try to use `sorted` function:

```
items = [5, 6, 2, 2, 6, 5, 5, 5]
res = sorted(items, key = lambda n: items.count(n), reverse=True)
print(res)
```

However I'm very surprised by output:

```
[5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 2, 2, 6]
```

Why don't the 2 and 6 numbers doesn't sort properly? I understand that 6 and 2 numbers happen twice, but why does the sorted function mix them?

Comment: They _do_ sort properly. They both have the same count, and Python's sort is [_stable_](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts). If you wanted to group like values, you'd need to break ties with e.g. `sorted(items, key = lambda n: (items.count(n), n), reverse=True)`.

Comment: Using `list.count` repeatedly on every element of a list is pretty slow. Instead you can count all elements at once with a `collections.Counter`: `from collections import Counter; from itertools import chain, repeat; result = list(chain.from_iterable((repeat(x, c) for (x,c) in Counter(items).most_common())))`; or alternatively, using both Counter and sorted: `counter = Counter(items); result = sorted(items, key=counter.get, reverse=True)`

Comment: FWIW, this code has a terrible time complexity. An improved version would use a `Counter` object that will be used by the `key` function

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well thank you for link to stable sort in Python. That was the most consice and useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

> why the 2 and 6 numbers doesn't sort properly?

They *did* sort properly.

I don't understand the nature of your confusion.
There's no difference between `2` and `6` in this context.
You exposed no information about their distinct identities
when you supplied `sorted` with a `key` function.

---

If you wish to retain distinct identities,
then instead of supplying just a `count`,
consider supplying a `(count, n)` tuple
during comparisons.

And project down, when reporting the final answer.
This is most conveniently accomplished
by asking the key function to
return such 2-tuples.

---

The [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)
is "used to extract a comparison key".
It's important to understand that the
stable sort being used
never sees the underlying list elements.
It only sees the comparison keys.
It compares them, and puts them in the order
that [timsort](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-timsort) dictates.

Comment: Or alternatively, `res = sorted(res)` _before_ sorting by frequency. Though this means more work.

Comment: @Chris More is less. At least quite often with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ops I have to correct lambda function in this way:

```
res = sorted(items, key = lambda n: (items.count(n), -items.index(n)), reverse=True)
```

and it worked!

Comment: Or just `key = lambda n: (items.count(n), n)`

Comment: But please note that using `items.count` repeatedly like that is terribly inefficient. Instead it is strongly recommended to use `collections.Counter(items)` only once, then refer to these counts.